# SSRS collapse empty field and collapse space also

Tags: reporting-services

**My problem in SSRS: address lines 2 and 3 have no data**

Pit ltd.

230 Sunset Blvd.

*Field: Address Line 2*

*Field: Address Line 3*

Singapore

**Solution should be:**

Pit ltd.

230 Sunset Blvd.

Singapore

**How can I collapse these fields and also save space?**

**Edit: Alle these fields have to be single fields placed on the canvas. I cannot use a table due to different formattings for the fields.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a visibility expression for the rows. You can also do this at a group level. Right click and go to row visibility.

[image]

Select "Show or hide based on an expression" radio button.

Click the expression button.

In the expression window, use `Fields!AddressLine2.Value = NOTHING`

Do the same for Address 3. Note I'm assuming your fields are named as displayed.

**Update**

For the same idea on a text box, just right-click the text box, go to text box properties, visibility, and use the same expression for the third option - "Show or hide based on an expression."

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that these have to be single fiields placed on the canvas. I cannot use a table due to different formattings for all the fields.

Comment: How are you getting the fields onto the canvas? Text box?

Comment: Yes, simple textboxes